# Play MediaPlayer In Background

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am building media player application in that on First Activity I am Showing All Song List and on song click i am playing song in media player. But when i back pressed i come to the song list again and again when i back pressed i come out of the application. I want that song should be continue to play when i come out of the application and when i resume to my application it continues to play.

Plz Suggest me some solution.

I have tried this code :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do whatever you desire
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    return;
}
```

But this is not working. When i resume to my application it throws error.

Comment: All you need is this. Use Service [mediaplayer using service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices)

Comment: if you want a quality mediaplayer not creating problem afterwards..follow the link below

Answer (score 0):

in the songsplay list activity, after the startactivity(intent) write finish();
it will finish() the activity, now we can press back button songsplay list activity will not appear.